# How to embedd video in WYSI HTML5 editor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am developing a tutorial website in which I want to display textual as well as video tutorial for users. To enter information and for formatting purpose I have used bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails editor. Using this editor I am able to add links, images and perform all basic functionality.  Now I want to add a button in the editor to add a video link which help me to add video path of my local video storage. I searched through many links but could not get the solution as required for my problem. By the way m using rails 3.2.2. Any help is appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Remove

line 4798 wysihtml5.js
change it like this:

```
return elementOrHtml //turn off parser//  isString ? wysihtml5.quirks.getCorrectInnerHTML(element) : element;
```

Original line:

```
return isString ? wysihtml5.quirks.getCorrectInnerHTML(element) : element;
```

will turn off the parser at all.

In

```
function parse(elementOrHtml, rules, context, cleanUp) {...
```

Comment: Thanks! This works in that I can now embed video. What side effects does turning off parser have?

Comment: none, the client side parser is not necessary at all, if you want to parse input do it at server side. (check i forgot the ; at the end) 
it is: 
return elementOrHtml;

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. I think it only works in IE > 8 though.

https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/pull/4

Comment: Hey thanks ped!! I asked this question many days ago but couldn't find any solution, I had also tried this solution but no achievement, so I tried a new editor ie tinymce it contain all the features. Video embedding is a easy process and many more feature are there.

Comment: Okay, but redactor editor does not fit into the licensing mode we are looking for (MIT, Apache etc.).... :(