# Issue with Wysihtml5 and Iframe for videos

Tags: javascript, iframe, video, youtube, wysihtml5

Using wysihtml5 by https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5, I've been trying to add a custom way to add videos. I tried the implementation of https://github.com/arvigeus/bootstrap3-wysihtml5/blob/master/src/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.js but when I'm currently running into 2 issues.

1) Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOHYCZLmbyc' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

2) When I submit the form the  part is being ignored.

**The output when I embed the iframe in the textarea is:**

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzWmhO4zw7M" allowfullscreen="">
    #document
      <html>
         <head>
         </head>
      </html>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

**The output in my log when I submit the form is:**

"text"=>"
"

where "text" is the column name in my db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a fix:

**1) Addind "/v" before "/watch" solved this issue**

I added a script that change the url from:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOHYCZLmbyc
```

to

```
https://www.youtube.com/v/watch?v=OOHYCZLmbyc
```

in my context I added this:

```
video.src = src["src"].replace("://www.youtube.com/watch", "://www.youtube.com/v/watch")
```

**2) I found a solution on stackoverflow that suggested to modify a line in the wyshtml5 script so that it ignores the parser:**

See the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17175438/834161